# HTML 100% width wider than page

Tags: html, css

For some reason, I can't make a webpage be exactly 100% width, it always seems to have a scroll bar. I've even gone back to basics and can't work it out, so hopefully its just me being daft!

Can someone take a look please

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #393939;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
Hello World
```

Comment: `</html> Is that on your live website as well?

Comment: `body` has default margins. Remove those and you'll be fine. Also, no need for `width: 100%;` for block level elements like `body`, it's somewhat redundant.

Comment: @scarsam no, that was just a typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clear the margins on the `body` using `margin: 0;`.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
    background-color: #393939;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    margin: 0;
}
```